# How to pass multiple arguments with cmd.exe from C#

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd, command, arguments

This is what I ve been doing:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments=@"/K cd/";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments=@"/K cd C:\Users\HP\Documents\NooJApp\_App";
cmd.Start();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

But it seems that the second argument is not working, because `cmd` is not responding to it, it only responds to the first argument.
So can anyone help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the executable you are running?  cmd.exe is the shell which requires an executable.  You can only have one string of Arguements so the 2nd one is the only one that is used.  "cd" isn't a valid input to the shell cmd.

Comment: What should the `cmd /K ...` command line be you want to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Arguments` only takes one string.  You can concatenate strings together to make one string, and you have to escape certain things as described [in this MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx)